# How to fix pip? Pip can't run main function

Tags: python, pip, conda

I tried to upgrade pip and run bdist_wheel, and now i get this. This error i get in anaconda too. I don't know how to fix it. I can't find the problem in google. [error in command line windows](https://sun9-58.userapi.com/c851236/v851236887/1f7bd0/Q-4oIHneRyM.jpg).[error in command line anaconda](https://sun9-17.userapi.com/c851236/v851236887/1f7c0f/Sl6sg4fTkQM.jpg)

Comment: How did you upgrade `pip`? Also, please replace the images with text (https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more descriptive to what you did, when you say:

> I tried to upgrade pip and run bdist_wheel, and now i get this.

I'm assuming that your pip was working before, so you may try running this (Windows Command Prompt):

```
py -3 -m ensurepip
```

or this in your Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda install pip
```